# CodingBat starOut, why using substring won't work correctly

Tags: java, string, substring

I am solving coding challenge on CodingBat.com. Here is the question:

> Given a string and a non-empty word string, return a version of the
>   original String where all chars have been replaced by pluses ("+"),
>   except for appearances of the word string which are preserved
>   unchanged.
>
> ```
> plusOut("12xy34", "xy") → "++xy++" 
> plusOut("12xy34", "1") → "1+++++"
> plusOut("12xy34xyabcxy", "xy") → "++xy++xy+++xy"
> ```

Here is my attempted solution:

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word)
{
  String ret = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - word.length() + 1; ++i) {
    if (str.substring(i, i + word.length()).equals(word))
      ret += word;
    else
      ret += "+";
  }
  return ret;
}
```

But is giving wrong outputs: giving too many plus signs. I don't understand why this shouldn't work. I suspect that the substring method is not returning enough matches, so the plus sign is appended. But I don't see why this maybe so.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing a few things wrong. I've corrected your code although there is probably a cleaner way to do this. I will explain what's changed below.

```
public static String plusOut(String str, String word)
{
    String ret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        int endIndex = i + word.length();
        if (endIndex < str.length() + 1
                && str.substring(i, i + word.length()).equals(word)) {
            ret += word;
            i = i + word.length() - 1;
        } else
            ret += "+";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

First mistake is that you are not looping over the whole content of `str` and therefore never reach the last character of `str`.

Another problem is that once you find a word, you don't "jump" to the correct **next** index in the loop, but still continue looping over characters of the found word, which results in additional `+` characters in your result string.

```
i = i + word.length() - 1;
```

In your solution, the above will put you to the next index of a character inside `str` that you should be looking at. Example:

In string `12xy34xyabcxy` looking for `xy`.

You will find that word `xy` starts at index `2` and ends at `3`.
At that point you have result string `++xy` after adding the found `word` to it.

Now, the problem begins. You **still** end up going over index `3` and adding an additional `+` because the next couple of characters do not add up to your word.

The 2 characters after the found `xy` also add `+` and you now have `++xy+++` which is incorrect.

```
endIndex < str.length() + 1
```

`endIndex` is named after what it is - end index of your substring.

This check prevents us from checking for `xy` when there aren't enough characters left in the string from current index to the last in order to make up `xy`, so we end up adding `+` for each remaining character instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a StringBuilder to construct the result to avoid creating multiple String objects as String in java is immutable:

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word) {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str);
  int len = str.length(), wordLen = word.length(), index = 0;
  while(index < len){
    if ( (index <= len-wordLen) && (str.substring(index, index+wordLen).equals(word))){
      index += wordLen;
      continue;
    }
    result.setCharAt(index++, '+');
  }
  return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: By far the most sensible solution I've seen. Would be nice to explain why the author's current implementation does not work though.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

```
public static String plusOut(String str, String word)
{
    String ret = "";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length() - word.length() +1 ; i++) {
        if (str.substring(i, i + word.length()).equals(word)) {
            ret += word;
            i += word.length() - 1;
        }
        else
            ret += "+";
    }
    while (i < str.length()) {
        ret += "+";
        i++;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Check your time complexity - you are looping twice.

Comment: Not twice just the rest of the length Bro. @curiousdev

Comment: Woops I missed the fact that you declared `i` above the loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```
    public String plusOut(String str, String word)
{
    String ret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length();) {
        if (i + word.length()<= str.length() && str.substring(i, i + word.length()).equals(word)) {
            ret += word;
            i+=word.length();
        }
        else{
            ret += "+";
            i++;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```